# MPI: Ensure an exclusive access to a shared memory (RMA)

Tags: algorithm, mpi, mutual-exclusion, mpi-rma

I would like to know which is the best way to **ensure** an exclusive access to a shared resource (such as memory window) among n processes in MPI. I've tried MPI_Win_lock & MPI_Win_fence but they don't seem to work as expected, i.e: I can see that multiple processes enter a critical region (code between MPI_Win_lock & MPI_Win_unlock that contains MPI_Get and/or MPI_Put) at the same time.

I would appreciate your suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In MPI 2 you cannot truly do atomic operations. This is introduced in MPI 3 using `MPI_Fetch_and_op`. This is why your critical data is modified.

Furthermore, take care with `MPI_Win_lock'. As described [here](http://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_Win_lock.html):

> The name of this routine is misleading. In particular, this routine need not block, except when the target process is the calling process.

The actual blocking process is `MPI_Win_unlock`, meaning that only after returning from this procedure you can be sure that the values from `put` and `get` are correct. Perhaps this is better described [here](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~thakur/papers/atomic-mode.pdf):

> MPI  passive  target  operations  are  organized  into access epochs that  are  bracketed  by MPI Win lock and MPI Win unlock calls. Clever MPI implementations [10] will combine all the data movement operations (puts, gets, and accumulates) into one network transaction that occurs at the unlock.

This same document can also provide a solution to your problem, which is that critical data is not written atomically. It does this through the use of a *mutex*, which is a mechanism that ensures only one process can access data at the time.

I recommend you read this document: The solution they propose is not difficult to implement.